# Gulp watch in docker takes too long in docker

Tags: docker, gulp

I have gulp watcher task which takes ~10s to run on host. But with docker it takes ~2min.

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    $.livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['scss']);
    gulp.watch(paths.oldscss, ['scss-2']);
    gulp.watch(paths.coffee, ['coffee']);
    gulp.watch(paths.icons, ['icon-font']);
    gulp.watch(paths.es6, ['es6']);

    gulp.watch(paths.css, $.livereload.reload);
    gulp.watch(["../shop/**/*.es6.min.js"], $.livereload.reload);
});
```

This is how i run my task:

```
docker run -p 35729:35729 --rm -it -v HOST_STATIC_PATH:CONTAINER_STATIC_PATH container bash -c "cd CONTAINER_STATIC_PATH && gulp watch"
```

I assume it's some sort of volumes sync problem. Because if i run command without volumes

```
docker run -p 35729:35729 --rm -it container bash -c "cd CONTAINER_STATIC_PATH && gulp watch"
```

it takes same ~10s as in the host machine.

Also, the default gulp build in docker takes acceptable amount of time.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Docker bind-mounts have some known performance issues, especially on MacOS hosts.  Can you run `gulp watch` from a Node environment running directly on your host instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze уes I can and do now. But we have ~10 developers and really tough-to-manage nodejs, ruby environments to build static. And we want to create one container (to rule them all)